# HTTP response times GUI

Tags: http, centos, port

I'm looking for an application available on CentOS, that allows me to check periodic connectivity response times between that server and a specific port of a remote server (in this case servers a SOAP API).

Something that preferentially allows me to send periodic API calls, but if not possible, just telnet's that remote port, but shows results in a graphic.

Does someone know about an application that allows this, without the need for me to create a script that writes results to a log file that is less readable in terms of time perspective?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After digging and testing a bit more, ended up using netdata:

https://www.netdata.cloud/

Awesome tool, extremely simple to use and install.